# Can I utilize T2 hardware based encryption for external SSD drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, encryption, filevault

Or should I preferably get external SSD which contains hardware based encryption baked in?

Why asking, because there are drives with and without hardware based encryption. For the latter if I could utilize T2 then there won't be performance penalty, if any using CPU for encryption if done by the T2.

Comment: This article contains all you need to know about encryption performance on external drives. https://eclecticlight.co/2023/03/03/whats-the-overhead-of-using-apfs-encryption/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using your Mac for encryption - not the external SSDs hardware encryption.

Makers of externals SSDs generally have a quite bad reputation for the security of their products. If a problem is found with the system (which is a realistic worry) - then are you sure they will tell you? - will they provide you with a fix?

The T2 chip cannot be use to hardware-accelerate encryption of external drives. However, in general, you do not need to worry about performance penalties in performing encryption with the CPU. If your computer has a T2 chip, the CPU is anyways fast enough that it doesn't really matter unless you have a really extreme scenario.

Also keep in mind that any Mac that has a T2 also have a CPU that has special, "hardware accelerated" AES instructions for performing encryption faster than using the generic instruction set.

Comment: & anecdotally, even an old 2012 MBP with swapped-in SSDs is fast enough that FileVault isn't noticeable. It should be no worry at all on a newer Mac.